# A function equivalent to SecKeyRawVerify on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, cryptography, digital-signature

I am trying to create a function that does the same job as the iOS `SecKeyRawVerify` (Verifies a digital signature.) for MacOSX (>10.6), but so far I was unable to do so. I wonder why Apple would provide such a function for iOS and without another one to do the same job for OSX?

Any help appreciated big time, I have been struggling with that all day long.

A brief description of the function for iOS:

> **SecKeyRawVerify**
>
> Verifies a digital signature.
>
> ```
> OSStatus SecKeyRawVerify (
>    SecKeyRef key,
>    SecPadding padding,
>    const uint8_t *signedData,
>    size_t signedDataLen,
>    const uint8_t *sig,
>    size_t sigLen
> );
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> `key`
>   Public key with which to verify the data.
>
> `padding`
>   The type of padding used. Possible values are listed in “Digital Signature Padding Types.” Use kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA1 if you are verifying a PKCS1-style signature with DER encoding of the digest type and the signed data is a SHA1 digest of the actual data. Specify kSecPaddingNone if no padding was used.
>
> `signedData`
>   The data for which the signature is being verified. Typically, a digest of the actual data is signed.
>
> `signedDataLen`
>   Length in bytes of the data in the signedData buffer.
>
> `sig`   The digital signature to be verified.
>
> `sigLen`   Length of the data in the sig buffer.
>
> Return Value   A result code. See “Certificate, Key, and Trust
>   Services Result Codes.”
>
> Availability
>   Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Comment: have you found a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

On OS X you have to use security transforms, something like:

```
CFErrorRef error;
SecTransformRef verifier = SecVerifyTransformCreate(publicKey,
                                                    (CFDataRef)signature,
                                                    &error);
if (error) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }

SecTransformSetAttribute(verifier,
                         kSecPaddingKey,
                         kSecPaddingPKCS1Key,
                         &error);
if (error) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }


/* Specify digest type */
SecTransformSetAttribute(verifier,
                         kSecDigestTypeAttribute,
                         kSecDigestSHA1,
                         &error);
if (error) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }

/* Raw data */
SecTransformSetAttribute(verifier,
                         kSecTransformInputAttributeName,
                         dataWithoutSignature,
                         &error);

CFTypeRef result = SecTransformExecute(verifier, &error);
if (error) {
    CFShow(error);
    exit(-1);
}

if (result == kCFBooleanTrue)
{
    NSLog(@"VERIFY: success.");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"VERIFY: failure, again...");
}
```